# RadioButtonList not firing on subsequent change event when value is set via javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, events

I have a RadioButtonList with 2 selections as ListItems with a server OnSelectedIndexChanged event and a clientside onchange event. Markup Code looks like this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdViewSelection" 
         runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true"
           OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdoSelection_SelectedIndexChanged"    
           onchange="SelectedIndexChanged();">
       <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Selected="True" 
            Text="1" Value="1"</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Selected="False" 
            Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Javascript method for the controls Client onchange event looks like this:

```
function SelectedIndexChanged() {
    var rdoSelection = document.getElementById("<%=rdoSelection.ClientID%>");
     for (var i = 0; i < rdoSelection.cells.length; i++) {
         for (var x = 0; x < rdoSelection.cells[i].all.length; x++) {
             if (rdoSelection.cells[i].all[x].checked) {
                 // Store value in Hidden Field
                 document.getElementById("<%=SelectedValue.ClientID%>").value = rdoSelection.cells[i].all[x].defaultValue;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

I also have a asp:LinkButton control that performs some server side actions when the user clicks it; but in addition to the server method that is called, there is also a onClientClick method that changes the selected Value of the RadioButtonList.

For simplicity I have removed all but the offending line of client code that is causing the issue I am having but it this looks like this:

```
function ChangeSelectedIndex()
{
    rdoSelection.cells[1].childNodes[0].checked = true;
}
```

When the selected node of the RadioButtonList is changed via the client code that is called from the LinkedButton, the value is successfully changed on the page and the Server OnSelectedIndexChanged event fires.

But if I manually click the unselected node (after the 1st programmatic change), the server side OnSelectedIndexChanged method is not called. But any selection change performed after that calls the server event successfully. Its as if the first manual change (after the change handled programmatically by the client method) is ignored as a ServerSide Event. Then any manual change after that falls back in sync with the server.

How can I ensure that every change event of the RadioButtonList triggers the server side OnSelectedIndexChanged event and why does changing the selected index via Javascript render the second manual change moot and functionality is resumed after that???

All these controls reside inside of a UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the RepeatDirection it should work.

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?